# RubyMineで編集中の該当行をGitのリモートサーバーのソースで表示する方法

Tags: ruby, rubymine

Gitでバージョンコントロールを行い、Bitbucketをリモートに指定してる状態でBitBucket上の該当行に移動する簡単な方法はありますか？

例えば`myproject`の`foo.rb`の43行目にカーソルがある時に下記のようなURLへ移動できる方法があったら楽だと思ったんですが、右クリックメニューの`Go to`や`Git`からはそれらしいものが見つかりませんでした。

https://bitbucket.org/ironsand/myproject/src/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app/models/foo.rb?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#foo.rb-43